# How can I get the source of a function not included in prelude using lambdabot?

Tags: haskell

I can get the source of functions from prelude:

```
lambdabot> src foldr
foldr f z []     = z
foldr f z (x:xs) = f x (foldr f z xs)
```

but I can't get the source from other modules:

```
lambdabot> src flatten
Source not found. Maybe if you used more than just two fingers...
lambdabot> hoogle flatten
Data.Tree flatten :: Tree a -> [a]
Data.Graph flattenSCC :: SCC vertex -> [vertex]
Data.Graph flattenSCCs :: [SCC a] -> [a]
lambdabot> src Data.Tree flatten
Source not found. Just try something else.
lambdabot> src Data.Tree.flatten
Source not found. Have you considered trying to match wits with a rutabaga?
lambdabot> src Tree flatten
Source not found. And you call yourself a Rocket Scientist!
lambdabot> src Tree.flatten
Source not found. Just try something else.
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't really do this. lambdabot uses a hard-wired file full of name->source mappings; it doesn't look up the source of an identifier in a particularly principled way.

The best you can do in general is `:i foo` in ghci to find out which module an identifier comes from, and then look up the source of that module (say, with [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/), which typically links to pages with source links).